# JS Dynamic imports synchronus

Tags: javascript, import

I am trying to build a localization feature in my javascript app, the locale function would load a [lang].json file based on the locale selected by the user.

I am using the following code

```
async function locale() {
     try {
        response = await import(`./lang/${locale}.json`);
        response = response[props.id] || "";
        return response;
      } catch (error) {
        response = await import(`./lang/en.json`);
        response = response[props.id] || "";
        return response;
      }
}
```

The problem with the above code is it returns a promise and I don't want to use await where ever i am calling the above function. Is there any workaround of using the above code without promises?

Comment: No, you can't make an async operation into a sync one.

Comment: on top of that, you can't import json in JS, unless you depend on tools, so I'd change those imports into `await fetch(...).then(b => b.json())`